# Should questions be marked with tags about intended use?

Tags: discussion

I think of Q & A in terms of storytelling by default.  How will working out an idea in that way be good for plot advancement, suspension of disbelief,  charactization, and tropes that readers are familiar with.

But if a question is meant for RPG, different needs are relevant and different shared background and culture is in play.

Should questions be tagged as to the domain?  What are the choices?

Comment: Are worldbuilding for a story and worldbuilding for an RPG all that different on the backend?

Comment: I agree with Samuel. Worldbuilding is about building a world; what you do with it is up to you. There are plenty of examples of a world made for one medium being used in another; just look at all the RPGs inspired by LOTR.

Comment: ... and the other way, the number of books on Forgotten Realms, Dragon Lance, etc. based on RPG.

Comment: This vaguely reminds me of [Can we post Questions for google users and should there be a Tag for them?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/172/29)

Comment: I'm not suggesting tags for specific rpg systems and fictional universes,  with the existing question base.  But rpg vs literature vs (what else) might be handy, with well thought out organization.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that **questions should not be tagged based on the purpose of asking the question.**

*Such meta-tags do not add any significant useful categorization of questions.* For example, the expertise needed to answer a [bookwriting](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookwriting) [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology) question should not be significantly different from that needed for answering the same question if it were tagged as [rpg-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-design) [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology); both would need someone reasonably able to answer a [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology) question, while the differences between answering the question for the purpose of bookwriting and RPG design should ideally be limited to nonexistent.

Instead, **if you have specific needs that you want answers to cater to, state those needs in the question.** Doing so also almost automatically makes it not a duplicate of any existing questions that do not have those specific needs stated.

Also remember we have the triad [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check), [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based), [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) already; pick the *one* of those that is most appropriate to your needs, and state any further needs (those not covered by the tag wiki) in the question body.

If you feel that it adds value, you can always (regardless of which tags you use to categorize the question) state in the question body "I'm designing an RPG world for Game ABC revision V, and...". This adds the relevant information, and is much more both specific *and/or* versatile compared to having a tag for every RPG game and revision in existence, let alone every book and movie genre as well. I would recommend stating something like that fairly early, but *not* right at the top of the question (because the latter would diminish the usefulness of the question excerpt).

Comment: I'm thinking of [this answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/how-does-one-design-a-city-meant-for-creatures-of-greatly-varying-sizes/30236#30236) which is specific to RPG. There are other discussions with rules of RPG, and I suppose my default position of considering tropes known to the audience would  be the opposite.  This made me consider that the useful answers are different for that purpose.

Comment: @JDługosz My answer, so I guess it falls to me to refute the argument. It is not actually specific to the RPG, it is specific to the magic system of the specified setting. Which just happens to be detailed in the rule book for the RPG. The important thing here is that specifying it is for an RPG use would add nothing over just describing the magic system and that there is absolutely nothing restricting the answer or the magic system to RPG use. People **do** write novels using these settings.

Comment: @JDługosz Tags for specific settings or game systems would work and be useful, but I doubt we get enough of these questions for it to be worth it.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of specific systems, but the recent answers referring to game rules might in fact be system specific.  If the answer read, "well, in xxx rpg system we have yyy which basically describes what you want" then it would be no different than when I say "author bbb does something similar in the novel dddd". But simply siting rules like they're both already playing the same game makes me think that the discussion is *in* that game as a given.  Makes me feel like I shouldn't bother with "outside" ideas.

Comment: @VilleNiemi If you feel you have a different answer, then please post it as an answer so the community can vote on alternatives.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I agree with your answer to **this** question, just pointed out that for **another** similar question the answer might be yes.